# HTML/CSS: Table width same as div

Tags: html, css

I want to create a form that contains a table. I used div and inside div, there is a table.
I want the table width is the same as the div width. The div width is 100%. But the result is, the table width is not fit as the div width. Below is the code:

```
<body >
<div width = '100%' align='center'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't use the `table` tag for layout. It should only be used for tabular data which this is most certainly not.

Comment: First, for `div` and `table` use `style`. `div style="width:100%; text-align:center"` and for table `tavle style="width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the width for the table to be 100 %.

```html
<style>
    div {
      background-color: lightblue;
     }
    table {
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
    <body >
    <div width = '100%' align='center'>
      <table width = '100%'>
         <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Please note the `width` attribute is now obsolete for `table` and `div` (actually most tags): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with style directly in html, you need to use the attribute `style=""` in your tag. You will have to add some CSS rules such as `width: 300px;`

See my code snippet and play with the width of the `<table style="">` to see what happens. I have set the div to have a width of 300px while the table covers only 90% of it's parent, which is the div. If you set the table's width to 100%, the red border will completly hide the div's border.

```html
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
        <table style="border: 2px solid red; width: 90%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```